# Database Entry Syntax Error

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion

I am trying to insert data into a database (sql server 2010) using cfqueryparam (coldfusion 10). I am not sure what I am doing wrong and why it it is throwing this error. It is saying I have a syntax error but does not tell me what line the syntax error is occuring. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**ERROR**

```
[Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]Incorrect syntax near '@P2'.
```

**Coldfusion**

```
<cfif (isDefined("session.checkout.quantity.pcount"))>
<cfquery datasource="Titlesbymail" name="InsertEntry">
     INSERT INTO Customer (FirstName, LastName)
     VALUES (
        <cfqueryparam value='#session.checkout.info.firstname_1#' cfsqltype='cf_sql_nvarchar' />
       , <cfqueryparam value='#session.checkout.info.lastname_1#' cfsqltype='cf_sql_nvarchar' />
</cfquery>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example you are missing the closing parenthesis.

You have:

```
<cfquery datasource="Titlesbymail" name="InsertEntry">
 INSERT INTO Customer (FirstName, LastName)
 VALUES (
    <cfqueryparam value='#session.checkout.info.firstname_1#' cfsqltype='cf_sql_nvarchar' />
   , <cfqueryparam value='#session.checkout.info.lastname_1#' cfsqltype='cf_sql_nvarchar' />
</cfquery>
```

It should be:

```
<cfquery datasource="Titlesbymail" name="InsertEntry">
 INSERT INTO Customer (FirstName, LastName)
 VALUES (
    <cfqueryparam value='#session.checkout.info.firstname_1#' cfsqltype='cf_sql_nvarchar' />
   , <cfqueryparam value='#session.checkout.info.lastname_1#' cfsqltype='cf_sql_nvarchar' />
 )
</cfquery>
```

See if that fixes it.

Comment: [Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]The INSERT permission was denied on the object 'Customer', database 'TitlebyMail', schema 'dbo'.

Comment: why would it get denied?

Comment: Well you are passed the error in your original post. This new error means that the SQL account you are using in your datasource does not have permission to insert to that table.  The user needs rights on the database server and in the ColdFusion datasource (if you have changed that).